# Can't seem to be able to re alloc a released UIView

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uiview

I have a UIView which I create programmatically roughly like so:

```
@implementation SlideShowView
- (id)initWithImages
{
    …
    if (self=[super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)])
    {
        // init objects here
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    printf("dealloc slide show view\n");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"unlockUI" object:nil ];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"setUserRating" object:nil ];
    [mCurrentImageView release];
    [mRightImageView release];
    [mLeftImageView release];
    [mImages release];
    [queue cancelAllOperations];
    [queue release];
    [managingArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

with a uiview controller that contains this:

```
- (void)loadView {
{
    ...
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    self.slideShowViewObject = [[SlideShowView alloc] initWithImages];
    [self.view addSubview:slideShowViewObject];
    …
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    [slideShowViewObject release];
    [self.slideShowViewObject removeFromSuperview];
    printf("dealloc of slideshow view controller\n");
    [super dealloc];
}
```

this seems to be able to dealloc both the view controller and view but when I push this view controller back onto the stack I get the message with zombie enabled: -[SlideShowView retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x43ab160

should the alloc not be creating a new instance of the  view when the controller is pushed? I don't understand and after spending many hours reading through other posts as well as looking at memory guides I would say I'm thoroughly stumped! Can someone offer any pointers? I only posted the code I deemed necessary but I can post more if need be.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't call both `[super init]` and `[super initWithFrame:]`, only one of the two in your UIView subclass.

Secondly, you should only set `self.view` in a view controller in the `-loadView` method, which is designed for you to create your views. Normally, unless you need to do certain types of setup such as initializing variables, etc, you shouldn't need to override `-init` in UIViewController subclasses.

Comment: thank you for the response. I have made those edits to my code as well as the post above. I still have the same problem though. Might you possibly have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

finally, after finagling with the code again tonight I finally got it working. The key piece I was not releasing appears to be

```
[self.view release];
```

I suppose this makes perfect sense since I was adding the view as a subview of this alloc'd self view, but I had tried this before. Perhaps cleaning up the code is what made it work this time.